# Python error occurred during crontab scheduled launch

Tags: python, error-handling, cron, key-value

I have python script

```
df2['segm'] = df2.apply(lambda x: x.idxmax(), axis = 1)
```

and error occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/data/workspace/notebooks/crontab_procedures/proc_TrxAct_CC.py", line 310, in <module>

    df2['segm'] = df2.apply(lambda x: x.idxmax(), axis = 1)

  File "/opt/sdp/b2cml/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3645, in __setitem__

    self._set_item_frame_value(key, value)

  File "/opt/sdp/b2cml/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3788, in _set_item_frame_value

    self._set_item_mgr(key, arraylike)

  File "/opt/sdp/b2cml/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3802, in _set_item_mgr

    self._mgr.insert(len(self._info_axis), key, value)

  File "/opt/sdp/b2cml/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 1235, in insert

    raise ValueError(

ValueError: Expected a 1D array, got an array with shape (0, 7)
```

I tried this script executed in JupiterLab and there was no error

Comment: We cant take that one liner and put it in python to test.  Provide a [mcve]